# How can I store custom HTTP headers in browser?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Need help from experienced developers in web-developing. I use custom HTTP headers which I send from backend to frontend. 
And the question is can I store and use these custom HTTP headers by the default in the browser without JS only pure HTML or I should use JS in this case? Cause when I send request from the browser to the backend, it sent without my custom HTTP headers.

```
def auth():
    data = request.json
    login = request.form.get("login", "")
    password = request.form.get("password", "")
    # login = data.get("login", "")
    # password = data.get("password", "")
    resp = requests.post(auth_url+"/api/auth", json=dict(login=login,      password=password))

    if resp.json().get("auth", False):
        value = resp.json().get("value", "")
        response = make_response(redirect("/registration_journal"))
        response.headers["const_token"] = value.get("const_token", "")
        response.headers["temp_token"]  = value.get("temp_token", "")
        return response
    else:
        return redirect("/")
```

And after that, if I send some requests from frontend it sends without my headers, I check this in developer tool in browser.

Comment: What is the use case? Are you trying to default form submission headers?

Comment: add code to check

Comment: as I understand, the browser didn't store custom headers